# Expressing a linear functional as a finite linear combination of continuous linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $X$ be a linear space and $\{l_a\}$ be a family of linear functionals on it. Give $X$ the weakest topology that makes $l_a$'s continuous.

Then if $l$ is a linear continuous functional on $X$ for the topology defined above, I have to show that there exists some finite subset $\{l_i \} \subset \{l_a\}$ and positive constant $c$ such that $\mid l(x) \mid \leq c\sum \mid l_i(x) \mid $ holds for all $x$. But I am just totally stuck.... A hint tells me to think of the basic open set of the origin. But all I can think of is that the inverse image by $l$ of an open set containing $0$ has a basic open set in it. How on earth can I derive the above inequality from this fact??

It is so extremely frustrating....Could anyone please explain?

Comment: Could you please clarify the quantifiers here? Instead of putting "for all $x$, some $l_i$, and a constant $c$" after the expression, could you please put them before the expression, in correct order? Remember, $\forall$ and $\exists$ don't commute, so order is important.

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by "some $l_i$"? Does the set of index $i \in I$ depend on $l$?

Comment: OK I will edit to correct them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist $n \geq 1$, $l_1,l_2,...l_n$ in the given family and positive numbers $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$ such that $|l_i(x)|<r_i$ for each $i$ implies $|l(x)| <1$. Claim: if $l_i(x)=0$ for all $i$ then $l(x)=0$. To see this just note that $|l_i(kx)| =0<r_i$ for all $i$, so $|l(kx)| <1$ for every positive integer $k$. Hence $l(x)=0$. Now the conclusion follows from the following basic lemma in linear algebra:

if $l,l_1,...,l_n$ are linear functionals on a vector space such that $\cap_i ker (l_i) \subset ker (l)$ then $l$ is a linear combination  of $l_1,l_2,...,l_n$.

Comment: Wow.......thank you so much....

Comment: @OrestBucicovschi Yes, thank you for the correction.